# Pattern matching the data type of the first element in a list

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to do the following here

```
data M = A DataA | B DataB | C deriving (Eq, Show)
data DataA = DataA {aInt::Int} deriving (Eq, Show)
data DataB = DataB {bInt::Int} deriving (Eq, Show)

myFunction :: [M] -> Int
myFunction [] = 0
myFunction (m:rest) = 
    -- if m is A doSomething1
    -- if m is B doSomething2
    -- if m is C doSomething3
```

I can match the type of C, but not the other two.

I have tried things like

```
myFunction ((DataA m):rest) = doSomething1
myFunction ((A m):rest) = doSomething1
myFunction ((m::DataA):rest) = doSomething1
myFunction ((m::A):rest) = doSomething1
myFunction (m:rest) = case m of A -> doSomething1
                                B -> doSomething2 --etc
```

with no luck. What's the best way to achive this in Haskell?

Comment: I don't understand your problem.  I see the `myFunction ((DataA m):rest) = ...`  is obviously broken because `DataA` is not a constructor of `M` and should instead be `myFunction (A (DataA val) : rest) = ...` or something similar to that (like your second line).  Is that what you're wanting?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using `data M = A { mInt :: Int } | B { mInt :: Int } | C` and avoid the additional `DataA, DataB` types, which cause values to be wrapped inside two constructors (?)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this was just a simplified version of my code, I need those additional types =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is just "more pattern matching".  I think you are getting confused between the constructors for one type and another.

The `M` type has three constructors, `A`, `B`, and `C`. You should match one of these to obtain the field (if any) before trying to pattern match on your `Data{A,B}` constructors.

```
data M = A DataA | B DataB | C deriving (Eq, Show)
data DataA = DataA {aInt::Int} deriving (Eq, Show)
data DataB = DataB {bInt::Int} deriving (Eq, Show)

myFunction :: [M] -> Int
myFunction [] = 0
myFunction (m:rest) = 
    case m of
       A (DataA a) -> a
       B (DataB b) -> b
       C -> myFunction rest
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn't understand what A and B exactly stand for. Now it makes sense thinking of them as constructors

Comment: Is there a way to omit `a` from line `A (DataA a) -> a` ? My actual data type(`DataA`) have more than 1 field, but I won't be using them on the RHS of that line.

Comment: Sure, with record syntax: `A (DataA {}) -> someValue`